# why is a cylinder lock key not symmetrical?

Tags: lock

If you look at a mortice lock key from the side (https://tradelocks.co.uk/cylinder-mortice-borg-locks/key-blanks/6-lever-mortice-key-blank.html), it is symmetrical from tip-to-base. This is because the same key can be inserted into the same lock from either side of the door.

however, on some doors with simple cylinder locks (like this) https://www.easykeys.com/381_Yale_Lock_1-1600_Lock_Keys.aspx the key can also be inserted from either side of the door, yet it is not symmetrical.

how does this work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The mortise lock type for the key that you depict has a single locking mechanism that can be reached by the key inserted from either side of the door.

The cylinder lock you refer to is actually *two separate cylinders* that are keyed alike, that each have a simple rod at their back that activates the lock mechanism.

Comment: Thanks - I had actually wondered if that was the case on account of the fact that the mortise lock keys are much longer

Comment: That's extra fun when you're in a key control system like Primus, and you have two cores at $90 each... Seriously one reason mortice locks went away is it's usually illegal to lock a door on the inside now.  Too many burnt bodies have been found right next to such doors.  In fact now, commercial doors must swing out with a push bar, because people inhaling smoke are too addled to handle more.

Comment: @Harper Illegal in what sense? Surely I can put whatever lock I like on my own doors?

Comment: @Dan it's a fire safety thing, same as the electrical codes...

Comment: @Dan On doors with double cylinders, many people leave the key in the inside cylinder whenever people are present, but remove it when the building will be empty. Even that may violate some local codes.

Comment: @bib: FWIW, I lived in an apartment with double cylinders where the key on the inside one actually *broke off in the slot*. Fortunately the door had glass panels that could have been broken out if needed, and I was able to turn and remove it with pliers anyway after spraying in lubricant, but it was a good lesson in why this is an idiotic configuration.

Comment: @harper is that true even for a deadbolt that is right next to a window? i.e. within arms reach of someone who broke the glass?

Comment: @Harper: Another factor is that back in the day when such locks were popular, homes were sufficiently drafty that a keyhole that went all the way through a door wouldn't make much difference.  As the quality of insulation has improved, heat loss through a shared keyhole becomes much more of an issue.

Comment: @Brad: I don't see why it wouldn't be. The safety issue is the same, and securing against someone who broke the glass doesn't really make sense anyway; if they're willing and able to break the glass they can just enter through the broken window.

Comment: @Brad If you have a modern door and windows, they will have tempered glass.  It's not like they can just wrap their hand in a rag and punch through like back in the day.  I once had a door installer who was really reluctant to install double barrel locks because they had a client whose whole family died in a fire when they couldn't get out.

Comment: @Brad If you can, you should leave doors closed behind you when leave a burning building. This is so that air does not get in and feed the fire. In this scenario a smashed window is like an open door feeding the fire with bonus sharp bits! Doubly bad. That is assuming you can see which window to smash in the smoke.

Comment: @Harper -- it is possible to get mortise locks in a single cylinder (outside key, inside thumbturn) config, but aye -- double cylinders are risky business.

Comment: @threephaseeel I'd think it would be easy. Just fit a blank plate.

Comment: @DarcyThomas my question is not about fire but about burglar security.

Comment: @JimmyJames maybe I should consider replacing my lock now that my windows aren't from the 1930s.